# how to hide a vertical column in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

My jqGrid library version is 4.4.3.

[image]

How to remove/hide the red color vertical column? I added this extra vertical column because I want to place my priceCatGrid slightly below right of 'Product Name'. If remove this extra vertical column, my priceCatGrid's location will be directly below the starting of 'Product Code', which is not what the user wants.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hfbdsL7j/43/ contains the codes, however, not sure why could not get it to load.If got it to load, it will be as per above picture.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I see a error in your code - the name in colModel should not be empty as you do. In all cases the name should be present and it should not contain spaces.

There are a methods called showCol and hideCol, which do what you want.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("hideCol", "name_of_the_column")
```

where **name_of_the_column** should be existing name of colModel and should not be empty string.

Comment: I have modified my code locally, put in a name for colModel. The problem is after I hide this column, this column disappears and causes its priceCatGrid's location to be directly below the starting of 'Product Code', which is not what the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help, I have found that using .css('visibility','hidden') instead of hide achieves my objective.

Comment: https://www.use.com/OhONO  However, after I use .css('visibility','hidden'), the image is as shown in url, there is a blank vertical white space and the bottom grey line has disappeared, can anybody help?

Comment: It is ok, I have met my objective using other techniques. Thanks.